# Return Union Type instead of Union Case

Tags: f#

I have a union type like this

```ml
  type AccountCreated =
    { Owner: string
      AccountId: Guid
      CreatedAt: DateTimeOffset
      StartingBalance: decimal }

  type AccountDebited =
    { To: Guid
      From: Guid
      Description: string
      Time: DateTimeOffset
      Amount: decimal }

  type AccountCredited =
    { To: Guid
      From: Guid
      Description: string
      Time: DateTimeOffset
      Amount: decimal }

  type AccountEvent =
    | Created of AccountCreated
    | AccountCredited of AccountCredited
    | AccountDebited of AccountDebited
```

And another Union type like this:

```ml
 type RegisteredAccount = {
      Owner: string
      Balance: decimal
      AccountId: Guid }
  
  type Account =
    | Unregistered
    | Registered of RegisteredAccount
```

There's a function `evolve`:

```ml
  let evolve state event: Account =
    match event with
      | Created accountCreated ->
          { AccountId = accountCreated.AccountId
            Owner = accountCreated.Owner
            Balance = accountCreated.StartingBalance }
      | AccountDebited accountDebited ->
          match state with
          | Registered s -> 
              { s with
                  Balance = s.Balance - accountDebited.Amount }
          | _ -> failwith "unregistered account can't be debited"
      | _ -> failwith "todo: other cases"
```

`evolve` should be used using `List.fold`:

```ml
let build = List.fold evolve
let rebuild = build Unregistered
```

If I don't explicitely specify the return type of `evolve` as `Account`, I get this error for the line `let build = List.fold evolve`:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a 'Account -> AccountEvent -> Account' but given a 'Account -> AccountEvent -> RegisteredAccount' The type 'Account' does not match the type 'RegisteredAccount'
```

If set the return type of `evolve`, I get the compiler error in the pattern match for `Created` and one similar for `Registered` inside the `AccountDebited` pattern match.

```
This expression was expected to have type 'Account' but here has type 'RegisteredAccount'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue in your code is that the `evolve` function tries to return a value of the `RegisteredAccount` record type rather than a value of the `Account` union type.

I see you want to use `Unregistered` value (of type `Account`) as the initial value and you also added a type annotation specifying that the return type of `evolve` should be `Account`. I think this is actually what you want. The only thing missing is that you need to wrap the returned values using the `Registered` union case to turn `RegisteredAccount` into `Account`.

The following type-checks fine for me:

```
let evolve state event: Account =
  match event with
    | Created accountCreated ->
        { AccountId = accountCreated.AccountId
          Owner = accountCreated.Owner
          Balance = accountCreated.StartingBalance } |> Registered
    | AccountDebited accountDebited ->
        match state with
        | Registered s -> 
            { s with
                Balance = s.Balance - accountDebited.Amount } |> Registered
        | _ -> failwith "unregistered account can't be debited"
    | _ -> failwith "todo: other cases"
```

All I had to do is to add `|> Registered` in two places where you are returning a record!